# How to return specific fields in nested FB graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want to get a list of recent posts and for each post, a small number of insights fields.

Right now I'm only able to get back all possible insights with this one.

```
69001530484/posts?fields=id,name,insights{values, name}
```

I'd like to do something like this where i can receive only the insights fields i need.

```
69001530484/posts?fields=id,name,insights{values, name=[post_impressions,post_fan_reach] }
```

Comment: On Graph API GET requests you cannot do any generic kind of filtering. Some endpoints - however - do have this feature. The ads insights edge is a good example of this.